# how to make buttons FLAT on tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

Hello beautiful community. I am working on a tkinter GUI on a raspberry. Well first i started programming my gui on windows and i wanted to make my buttons look flat on screen without any lines on the edges and using **relief='flat'** worked well, But when i finished my project and i ran my program on my raspberry my buttons had those lines on the edge it seems like **relief='flat'**  doesnt have any effect and i tried to use **relief=FLAT** and still same problem

Here you can see a Screenshot of the running program and lines arround my buttons

[image: a Screen shot of my raspberry screen]

and here's my code

```
bouton_break = Button(f2, image=img_break, relief='flat' , command = break_ )  #break
bouton_break.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=134, width=107, x=40 , y=200)
bouton_MM = Button(f2, image=img_MM, relief='flat', command=maint_page)
bouton_MM.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=134, width=107, x=170 , y=200)
boutonlogout = Button(f2, image=img_logout , relief='flat', command = logout_cmd)  #logout
boutonlogout.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=134, width=107, x=300 , y=200)
```

Comment: what makes you think that nothing will fix that?

Comment: perhaps that's the highlight ring rather than the border that you're seeing. Have you tried setting `highlightthickness` to zero? You should also try setting `borderwidth` to zero as well.

Comment: @BryanOakley you're the best Thank you ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that what you're seeing is the focus highlight ring. This is used to let the user know which button has the keyboard focus.  To turn that off set the `highlightthickness` to zero:

```
bouton_break = Button(..., highlightthickness=0)
```

If you don't want to turn it off, you can still get a more visually clean appearance by making sure the `highlightbackground` option to the same color as the background so that it effectively disappears when the button doesn't have focus.

Answer (score 9):

Set button border = 0.

```
bd=0
```

(extra caharacters to satisfy SO)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
button_break = Button(f2, image=img_break, relief='flat', highlightthickness=0, bd=0, command=break_)
button_break.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=134, width=107, x=40, y=200)
button_MM = Button(f2, image=img_MM, relief='flat', highlightthickness=0, bd=0, command=maint_page)
button_MM.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=134, width=107, x=170, y=200)
button_logout = Button(f2, image=img_logout, relief='flat', highlightthickness =0, bd=0, command=logout_cmd)
button_logout.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=134, width=107, x=300, y=200)
```

Comment: Actually setting **highlightthickness** and **borderwidth** to zero worked!

Comment: That's great news. I've updated my answer to reflect that.